# Grails domain class validate() returns false but no error

Tags: grails

In the below code validate() is returning false but I am not seeing any errors. As the validate method is failing the data is not getting persisted to the database.

```
if (!stockInstance.validate() && stockInstance.save(flush: true))
 //redirect(action: "show", id: saleInstance.id)
} else {
 println 'stock instance has errors'
 stockInstance.errors.each {
 println it
}
render(view: "edit", model: [saleInstance: saleInstance])
}
```

This is printing

```
stock instance has errors
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors
```

So where else could the error be.

**Sorry was not watching the data properly, It was getting persisted correctly.**

Comment: maybe the save part is failing, try removing the : && stockInstance.save(flush: true) to see which part is failing

Comment: @RayTayek In my intial version of code I only had that. save() method was not persisting to the database with the same result. So I put the validate() method up front.

Comment: so validation is ok and the save is failing. try putting a logSql=true in your datasource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `!stockInstance.validate()` but it should be `stockInstance.validate()`.

`!stockInstance.validate() && stockInstance.save(flush: true)` can never be true since `save()` calls `validate()` so it becomes `!stockInstance.validate() && stockInstance.validate()`

It's not persisting since the `save()` call doesn't happen since the `validate()` call returns `true` (so the 1st check is false).

Since `save()` calls `validate()` I'm not sure why you have the extra call there though.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith...Got that..will test...My actual problem was that save() was not persisting to the database and there were no error from validate method. I will have to try what RayTayek suggested.